# How to make a really basic reference?

Tags: cross-referencing, pdf, links

I'm trying to make a really basic reference.

Let's say I have theses lines in my document :

```
Lorem Ipsum ...
Lorem Ipsum ... [1] here ... Lorem Ipsum ...
Lorem Ipsum ...
```

I want to anywhere in my document make a reference to `[1] here`.

I thought it would be simple to find out but I searched for too long and I got confused with all the sets and making a simple reference now seems to be like rocket-science to me.

> I want the following result :

[image]

When clicking on the colored number `1`, the line `[1] here` get at the top of my document viewer so the user feels easy to find the line directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `hyperref` package provides the pair of commands

```
\hypertarget{<name>}{<text>}
\hyperlink{<name>}{<text>}
```

for the creation of cross-references that are *independent* from counters. They are analogues of `\label` and `\ref`, respectively. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Go to the \hyperlink{lip}{second}, or  \hyperlink{lipsys}{third} paragraph.
\newpage
The first hyperlink brings you \hypertarget{lip}{here.}
\newpage
The second hyperlink brings you \hypertarget{lipsys}{here.}

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, if you wish associate cross-references to a counter, you can try using the following declarations:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red]{hyperref}

\newrobustcmd*{\foo}[1]{{\refstepcounter{bar}\label{#1}\thebar}}

\newcounter{bar}
\renewcommand{\thebar}{\textcolor{black}{[}\arabic{bar}\textcolor{black}{]}}

\begin{document}

Go to \ref{lipsys}, and \ref{lip}.
\newpage
The second hyperlink brings you \foo{lip} here.
\newpage
The first hyperlink brings you \foo{lipsys} here.

\end{document}
```

In the example above, `\foo{<key>}` (1) globally increments the counter `bar`, (2) maps the *key* to the current reference string, and (3) prints the value of `bar`. `\textcolor{black}{...}` is used to override the formatting applied by the `hyperref` package (otherwise it's typeset in the same colour as the counter).

[image]

Comment: perfect ! thank you, it was not that hard finally and now my document has the look I want, Regards~

Comment: and +1 for the counter solution